# Exact error message in shell script with line number

Tags: sql, oracle, shell

I have a shell script which has the following command :

```
LOGFILE=XX`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S`.log
LOG_PATH=`echo $CUR_DIR/$LOG_FILE`

echo "Creating Custom Package, Synonyms and Grants..."
echo    "">>$LOGFILE

if sqlplus $APPS_USER @Alter_table_script.sql
then
    echo "Custom table created successfully in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Custom table created successfully in APPS schema" 
else
    echo "Error in creating custom  table in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Error in creating Custom table  in APPS schema" 
fi
```

Alter_table_script is a sql file with alter and create statements. Now few of the statements have failed but in the log i do not have the exact errors and line captured instead it is showing `Custom table created successfully in APPS schema`  How do i capture the exact error in this file ?

Comment: Using `spool` as part of Alter_table_script.sql and copying the spooled file into $LOGFILE may help

Comment: @learningloop-This will come in if then part ?
Something like spool $LOGFILE ?